# File splitting Based on Column Name With `awk` Fails

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I've tried:

1. `awk '{if (last != $1) close(last); print > $1; last = $1}' file`
2. `awk -F$'\t' '{ print > ($1) }' file`
3. `awk '{if (last != $1) close(last); print >> $1; last = $1}' file`

To split a very large text file (33GB) into multiple files named by first column.

For smaller files everything works fine but for large files `awk` stops near the end of column type (commands 1 and 2) or forgets to input newline characters for columns that have "." in them (command 3).

Example: it just stops before reaching real end of column of type "10"

```
10      69331427        1
10      69331428        1
10      69331429        1
10      69331430        1
10      69331431        1
10
```

EDIT : 
Closing the file seems to help.
`'{print >> $1; close($1)}'`

GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: Fixed the first one. Closing the file does seem to help. All three commands are approved answers in different questions regarding the same problem. That's why I found it odd that it creates 99% proper files and then just cut in the end.

Comment: Btw, if you use
"""awk '{print >> $1; close($1)}' testing"""

with testing containg

"""AAEX03026070.1 1676 0
AAEX03026070.1 1677 0"""

(tab separated)
it will look different in midnight commander (mc) view mode F3 in raw and parsed mode. I belive this might be a bug.
The file has normal "\n" characters but mc ignores them for some reason. This happens only when first column is not a number and has a ".".

Comment: idk what "midnight commander" is but if it's some kind of text editor and if by "it" in your statement `it will look different...` you mean the input file - maybe that's an indication that your input file contains undesirable control characters?

Comment: So it sounds like you have 2 different tools (awk and mc) that are both exhibiting unexpected behavior when operating on your input file. Look to your input file....

Comment: As for the strange behavior of mc that pushed me to make this poor thread, look at this :

1. Parsed text
https://postimg.cc/bDZxBMfd
2. Same file in Raw mode
https://postimg.cc/RJfcMHFB
3. file content in od

https://postimg.cc/87ThSsg2

Strange, huh?
Lines not starting with  "."  behave normally like (2).

Comment: You should never use `{print > $1}` without checking if `$1` is a proper as a file name (no `/`, `/../`, NUL bytes) and without closing it afterwards -- even if GNU awk closes files automatically, that will keep thousands (`ulimit -n`) of open files around, putting pressure on your system and triggering bugs.

Comment: That being said, it looks more like a bug in `mc`, unless you mixed up those images.

Comment: Yes it does look like a bug in mc. This mc bug made me believe at first that awk creates double columns while splitting lines with non numeric first column for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

To "To split a very large text file (33GB) into multiple files named by first column." using GNU awk on any UNIX box is this:

```
awk '{print > $1}' file
```

That's all. If you're running into problems then it's something outside of your awk command that's causing it, e.g. maybe you're running out of space on your drive or maybe your input file contains some weird control characters.

I don't know what you mean by `awk stops near the end of column type`, nor `forgets to input newline characters for columns that have "." in them`, nor `it just stops before reaching real end of column of type "10"`. That may partially be because there's nothing in your question to indicate what "column type" means to you.

Comment: For a  very large file with thousands of unique values in the first column, this may cause `awk` to run out of available file descriptors. This is probably why they try to deal with that by explicitly closing the file when needed.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, it won't. Gawk handles that internally, closing and re-opening files as necessary. It WOULD be a problem with some other awk but the OP is using gawk 4.1.4.

Comment: You appear to be correct. So it may be an unnecessary  precaution on the user's side. However I also read that "gawk’s ability to do this depends upon the facilities of your operating system, so it may not always work. It is therefore both good practice and good portability advice to always use close() on your files when you are done with them."  (from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html)) This may not be an issue on Linux though.

Comment: @EdMorton then you should write `gawk` instead of `awk` in your answer and mention that. But even with `gawk`, that is horribly dangerous, 1st because `$1` may contain `../..`, etc, and 2nd because `gawk` will accept NUL bytes in its input (which are invisible on terminal), but silently ignore & truncate them when using them in a filename `printf 'foo\0bar baz' | gawk '{print$1>$1}'`.

Comment: @mosvy no, there's no need to write `gawk` when you specifically state "using GNU awk..." and no it's not horribly dangerous - you don't need to protect against `/`s and NULs and other things when the posted sample input simply has all integers in that field.

Comment: @Kusalananda if the gawk folks REALLY wanted us to always close() files then they'd never have bothered to provide the functionality internally. **IF** there turns out to be a problem (which I've never heard of actually happening) **THEN** you can add `close()`s.

Comment: The OP posted a sample of their _output_ and wondered why they need to explicitly call `close()`. I rest my case -- I hope the mods will not delete my comments as they're wont to.

Comment: @mosvy right, their output is a copy of their input and they do NOT need to explicitly call `close()`.

Comment: They said that "EDIT: Closing the file seems to help".

Comment: @mosvy Right, it's probably flushing the output so they see more output and they think that's helping but it's still not solving or even addressing their real problem. The code I posted will work given a POSIX text file as input and enough space on their drive to write to. If it doesn't work then the real problem is NOT a lack of `close()`s in their script.

Comment: By column type I mean unique column ID ie chromosome. Chromosome 10 will produce file names "10" and chromosome 11 will produce "11". Sorry for messy thread. I haven't used Stack in ages.

Comment: >awk stops near the end of column type
a small number of lines in output files are constantly missing ie file "10" should have X lines but it has X-48 lines for example.

>nor forgets to input newline characters for columns that have "." in them

It was a problem with "mc" see my postimage comment above.

Without adding close() it will continue to fail. Anyway, thanks for all your help.

Using close() slows the entire process down but I can wait.

Comment: @osowiecki Clarifications should be made in the _question_, not in comments.

Comment: @osowiecki `10` is at the start of rows in your input data - are you mixing up the words "row" (horizontal) and "column" (vertical)? I don't see how `10` is a "column ID" in your data but I could imagine it being a "row ID".

Comment: GNU/awk does manage any number of concurrent output files, but last time I used this (for about 30,000 files) the performance was truly terrible. After the per-process limit of open files (2048 in Linux Mint) is reached, the closes and opens are arbitrary (in the sense it does not appear to use any LRU or MRU rule). Also, if you explicitly close, and your input is unordered, you have to >> append for subsequent uses. I ended up reading a million lines at a time into a hash (indexed on filename and sequence) and flushing the lot opening a single file at a time. I got a x2500 speed-up.